# Jgrapht edge color

Tags: java, graph-visualization, jgrapht, jgraph

I would like to change the color of my edges using Jgrapht so that I can show the correspondence in my whole graph. Let us assume there is an edge between nodes 1 and 2. I will highlight these nodes in (say) red color. I will find nodes 1 and 2 in the whole graph and show them in the red color and the remaining nodes in some other color. I see the file that creates the visualization is **SimpleTouchgraphApplet.java** In this file, I am adding statements like,

```
setBackground(Color.green);
setForeground(Color.cyan);
```

I added the above two statements in the init section. I also added the below statements in my main function.

```
Color defaultBackColor = new Color(0x01, 0x11, 0x44);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBackground(defaultBackColor);
frame.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
```

However, I do not see any change in the foreground or background color. Please let me know where am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the edge coloring can be added in the TouchGraphConverter.java file.

The following function constructs the nodes.

```
public Node convertToTouchGraph(
    Graph<V, E> graph,
    TGPanel tgPanel,
    boolean selfReferencesAllowed)
    throws TGException
{
    List<V> jgtNodes = new ArrayList<V>(graph.vertexSet());
    Node [] tgNodes = new Node[jgtNodes.size()];

    // add all the nodes...
    for (int i = 0; i < jgtNodes.size(); i++) {
        Node n;
        if (jgtNodes.get(i) instanceof Node) {
            // if our JGraphT object was a touchGraph node, add it unaltered
            n = (Node) jgtNodes.get(i);
        } else {
            // create a TG Node with a "label" and "id" equals to the
            // objects toString() value
            n = new Node(jgtNodes.get(i).toString());

        }

        // store this for edge-related creation below
        tgNodes[i] = n;
        tgPanel.addNode(n);
        tgNodes[i].setBackColor(Color.RED);
```

The last line, **tgNodes[i].setBackColor(Color.RED)** will make the node color to red in the generated graph.